# How can I use Javascript to error check an HTML form, including verifying fields are filled and filled correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I am trying to create a form on a webpage where Javascript/Jquery will perform client-side validation on the form. I need it to not only check that the required fields are filled in, but that they are filled in properly (i.e phone numbers are formatted 000-000-0000, emails have an @example.com at the end and two names are entered in the name field). I've been trying to find sample code online but the code I found mostly broke what I already had. Here is the code for *one* field of the form:

HTML:

```
    <div class="contactForm">
      <label for="phone">Phone: </label>
      <div id="errorphone" class="error"></div>
      <input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="000-000-0000" required>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    $("document").ready(function(){
      console.log("Loaded");
      $("#submit").click(function(){
        checkPhone();
      });

    $("#phone").change(function(){
      console.log("Something in phone changed");
      checkPhone();
    });

    function checkPhone(inputtxt){
      var phoneno = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
      if($.trim($("#phone").val())==""){
        $("#errorphone").html("<p>You missed your phone number</p>");
        $("#errorphone").addClass("showerror");
      }
      else if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno)==false){
        $("errorphone").html("<p>Please enter your number in the format 000-000-0000</p>");
        $("#errorphone").addClass("showerror");
      }
      else{
        $("#errorphone").html("");
        $("#errorphone").removeClass("showerror");
      }
    }
```

The Javascript *used* to work to check if the field was empty or not, but when I tried to add in code to verify that the formatting was right, *all* the Javascript stopped worked. Here is my original checkPhone function, before I tried to add formatting validation:

```
    function checkName(){
      if($.trim($("#name").val())==""){
        $("#errorname").html("<p>You missed your name</p>");
        $("#errorname").addClass("showerror");
      }
      else{
        $("#errorname").html("");
        $("#errorname").removeClass("showerror");
      }
    }
```

I'm using Sublime, and the else statement in the current Javascript isn't colored properly, so I'm assuming the issue might have to do with syntax because it seems like the else statement isn't being recognized anymore. But frankly, I'm not even sure if I'm going about formatting validation properly, and I'm sure there's an easier way to do the form validation entirely. I've also noticed that the current version of checkPhone has inputtxt as a condition, but the input type for the field is listed as phone. Maybe that's the problem?

Either way, any help in the method I'm using and how to proceed would be great.

Comment: your HTML has no `<form>` that's a bad start...

Comment: My entire form is wrapped with ```<form>```, I only included the code referring to the one section of the form to keep from copy/pasting huge chunks of code.

Comment: I would highly recommend the jquery validation plugin https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: for HTML5 we have https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation

Comment: What was the code for "all the JavaScript stopped working"? What errors were printed on the console?

Comment: @traktor53 I'm receiving the error, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at checkPhone" -- referring to the line where the else if begins. The error only appears if I type something into the "phone" field and click submit, though. No errors until I do that.

Comment: @SarahDiri your ```checkPhone``` function expects a parameter (```inputtxt```), yet you pass no parameter in the function calls.

Comment: @SarahDiri test using a better browser. Firefox won't  even compile the code and reports that `if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno)==false)` is missing a parenthesis after the condition.

Comment: @traktor53 It definitely is, I failed to notice myself but someone else answered with that solution. It should run with the added ) at the end, but it still doesn't check for proper formatting. It seems I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass the input in the field through the functions.

Comment: @PieterSteyn Dumb question, but how do I go about passing the parameter properly? I've tried everything I can think of, but I can't seem to get the user input in the phone field to go through the function.

Comment: @SarahDiri please see my answer below. I have shown you how to use the plugin I suggested, but if you do not want to use it I gave a working solution of your code below that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've stated in the comments, I recommend the [jquery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). Below is how you would validate your phone number using the plugin. If you read the documentation you'll see there are many many examples. Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6gojrte2/

HTML Markup:

```
    <form id="myform">
        <label for="phone">Phone: </label>      
        <input name="field" placeholder="000-000-0000"><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Validate!">
    </form>
```

The required scripts

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $( "#myform" ).validate({
      rules: {
        field: {
          required: true,
          phone: true     
        }
      }
    });

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("phone", function (phone_number, element) {
            phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
            return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&  phone_number.match(/^\(?[\d\s]{3}-[\d\s]{3}-[\d\s]{4}$/);
    }, "Invalid phone number");

});
</script>
```

However, if you do not want to use the plugin, here is the solution to your validation. I corrected a few errors.

```
<script>

 $("document").ready(function(){

      $("#submit").click(function(){
        checkPhone($('#phone').val());
      });
 });

    $("#phone").keyup(function(){      
      checkPhone($('#phone').val());
    });

    function checkPhone(inputtxt){

      var phoneno = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
      if($.trim($("#phone").val())==""){          
        $("#errorphone").html("<p>You missed your phone number</p>");
        $("#errorphone").addClass("showerror");
      }
      else if((inputtxt.match(phoneno))==false || inputtxt.length < 12){          
        $("#errorphone").html("<p>Please enter your number in the format 000-000-0000</p>");
        $("#errorphone").addClass("showerror");
      }
      else{       
        $("#errorphone").html("");
        $("#errorphone").removeClass("showerror");
      }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I didn't use the plugin, but I will experiment with it when I have some time, since it seems like the kind of tool I wish I'd known about going into this.

Answer (score 1):

```
else if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno)==false){
```

this line missing a close bracket

Comment: Wow, okay. I definitely stared at this too long. I kept double checking the curly brackets and not the parenthesis. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="phone" pattern="^\+?\d{0,13}" title="You missed your phone number" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="000-000-0000" required>
```

Comment: This would work, but it's HTML validation correct? I am supposed to use Javascript, inconvenient as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to get the value of the element and pass it to your validation function. In event handlers the `this` keyword is the element the event is firing from.

Change

```
 $("#phone").change(function(){
      console.log("Something in phone changed");
      checkPhone();
    });
```

To

```
 $("#phone").change(function(){
      console.log("Something in phone changed");
      //Pass the value of the element to the function
      checkPhone(this.value);
  });
```